# Remove white space in highchart area chart in R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

I am trying to remove the white space to the left of and right of the area chart (created in R using highchart) which is shown in red in the image below.[image]

My reproducible code:

```
library(highcharter)

type <- c("A", "B", "C", "D","A", "B", "C", "D","A", "B", "C", "D")
total <- c(3300, 6080, 2780, 14054, 3638, 6360, 2722, 14148, 2681, 4761, 2080, 10080)
year <- c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020)
df <- data.frame(type, year, total)

highchart() %>%

  hc_chart(type="area") %>%
  hc_add_series(data = subset(df, type == "D"), name = "D", type = "area", hcaes(x = year, y = total)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = subset(df, type == "B"), name = "B", type = "area", hcaes(x = year, y = total)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = subset(df, type == "C"), name = "C", type = "area", hcaes(x = year, y = total)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = subset(df, type == "A"), name = "A", type = "area", hcaes(x = year, y = total)) %>%

  hc_xAxis(title = "", categories = c("2018", "2019", "2020"))
```

I've looked around online but I don't know JavaScript so it's difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed hc_xAxis to use tickPositions instead of categories.

```
hc_xAxis(title = "", 
           min = 2018, max = 2020, 
           tickPositions = c(2018, 2019, 2020))
```